# Is fashion design, modelling, acting, painting allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, women, fashion-design

My family is very religious, and in my childhood they didn't let me opt for modelling and fashion design as a career! I had good grades and was forced to get into "good noble profession" for ladies. The problem is I am extremely depressed and not happy at all.  My personality is doomed but I can't find a way.

Is fashion design, modelling, acting, painting allowed in Islam?

Answer (score 5):

```
                   In the name of Allah the merciful the compassionate
```

All what a Muslim does should be for the sake of Allah. The exalted. In fact, the life of a Muslim must be the reflection of God's gratification. Knowing this point, you are allowed to choose your own career. Another thing which must be noted is the Islamic rules.
None of the mentioned jobs are haram until you respect God's rules. Being a **model** is not bad until you wear suitable hijab to cover your body and your inner pearl of being a Muslim women. You can be a **Muslim model** and teach other models that, being model necessarily doesn't mean to be without hijab. As Muslim **artist** you can be a life model for other women and attract more people to the peaceful religion of Islam by being respectful to Islamic beliefs.
You may find more detailed information by reading the answer to this question:

[Is there any problem in the art of sculpting and painting?](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa3338)

Comment: But doesn't being a model undermine the very concept of modesty for women in Islam? Isn't model job about promoting fashion and physical attractiveness of a women? Are they Islamic?

Comment: @infatuated If by modeling, we mean modeling with it's current status you're exactly right. But I mean to change it so as to become islamic (under certain circumstances). It's a step toward islamic life style. However, I know that there's no need to have models (men or women) to put people deeper in their desires and don't let them think of their real life requirements.

Comment: Now you're talking sense! But why not promoting what is genuinely Islamic in the first place? Why legitimizing people's base desires at all?

Comment: @infatuated We should move step by step. can we subject the society to drastic changes or we'd better make it move backward very gradually and basically?

Comment: Yes, as a strategy I agree with that. But I believe if people are enlightened about lofty ideals of Islam they will embrace them and aspire for them. We should not miss the chance to remind them.

Comment: the querier ask about modeling in its state now, she didn't refer that she will be open to create a business, here the modeling is Haram because being sexy is the first aim in order to sell the goods ... and Allah knows better ...

Comment: @hbforce I agree with you. Modelling in its state now is not accepted and is not allowed in islam.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem in any of these profession. What important is that you must follow Islamic protocols (as applicable).

For example

Fashion designing: if you design garments that does not violates Islamic dress code. Then there is no problem.

Modelling: you can be a model but within the bounds of hijab. And the product you are endorsing must be allowed in sharia.

Same goes for acting and painting.

**what important is not crossing the boundary.**

Comment: I put my same critique of @Mohammad Hossein's answer to you "But doesn't being a model undermine the very concept of modesty for women in Islam? Isn't model job about promoting fashion and physical attractiveness of a women? Are they Islamic?"

Comment: @infatuated NO NO NO ! models job is to present the product thats it.

Comment: Yes, but by adding a sexual flavor to it! Very Islamic! ;)

Comment: you should read my answer again. i already said  you should not violate our protocol.

Comment: well, i think by the word MODEL what you perceive is the one you see in FTV.( specially FTV midnight hot ). LOLs.

Comment: But I was wondering if one can be a model without "violating our protocol" because being a model is about exposing one's physical attractiveness which would be unIslamic even with hijab! Hijab is not about just covering the body, it's about modest look, conduct and behavior!

Comment: @Zia, I agree you to some extent, specially regarding your last sentence "what important is not crossing the boundary" , although dear infatuated could be right too (from another angle).

Answer (score 1):

In the name of Allah

I am a woman like you and I realize completely what you want , but today the purpose of  modeling industry not only is not suitable and good for women but also is just deceiving them and deviate their mind from the right and useful way of life . They just want women to think about their clothes and appearances and not think about the real purpose that it is being a great and sophisticated woman in the society. They use women as a tool for their advertising and their dirty purposes.

But as a Muslim women , I strongly recommend you if you are talented and interested in this field ,so please create a modeling industry for Muslim women because nowadays modeling industry is so attractive and they are confused about that . You can encourage them to have a beautiful and suitable Hijab that does not restricted them to work in the society freely. Thus you can show the real model of a Muslim woman like Hazrat Fatima.

Answer (score 0):

Sister,

First of all, the biggest mistake most Muslims do these days is that they don’t even know that who they are, and what is their purpose of life. You are property of Allah, you are made by Allah, For Allah. Your purpose in life is JUST to live this life in accordance with teachings of Allah (Quran) and not by your own whims and desires. Of course you felt bad that you had to leave your passion, career, fashion modelling, all these type of things are by all means 100% Haram in Islam.

Islam does not stops you from going and persue your career and passion, but ONLY, if it is in accordance with rules of Islam, otherwise a Big No. So always remember that before you were born, you were nothing, Allah gave you whatever you have, your life, your body, your beauty, your everything.

And just imagine, the creator who gave you this body, will you MIS-USE it and make Allah angry (by going into the dirtiest industry of Fashion and modelling? where women are treated as JUST objects? and only Filth?? degrades women below level of gutter)...

Believe me sister all of us get very upset that why certain actions are haram, but in the end, when some people dis-obey Allah, then they do know some time that if you will ever go against Allah, then obviously you will face serious consequences. So please try to know your purpose of life, and stick to it. Otherwise you will be among the losers.\

May Allah guide us all